# Apache redirect directive not acting as final rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to achieve a simple redirect - from `/news` to `/insights`

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
redirect 301 /news /insights

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Whenever I've used the `redirect` directive before, any matched URLs would be redirected and no further rewrites in the file would be processed. That is to say, going to `/news` would send you to `/insights`, and the rewrite to `index.php` would not be processed.

However, with this current setup, going to `/news` sends me to `/insights?p=news`, so for some reason the rewrite to `index.php` is still being processed.

Furthermore, if I comment out the `index.php` rewrite, then I get sent to `/insights` as expected.

This isn't how I've usually experienced this working so am unsure why it's doing this.

I have also tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/news" "/insights" [R=301,L]
```

This simply results in a 404 instead of redirecting, which I also do not understand.

I am aware I could do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/news"
RewriteRule ^ /insights [R=301,L]
```

which does work, however, I don't really want to have multi-line rewrites for lots of URLs, and would like to understand why the other 2 examples do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to insert this rule before last catch-all rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/?$ /insights [R=301,L,NC]
```

Place it just below `RewriteEngine On` line so that `mod_rewrite` engine executed this rule before other rule.

Make sure to test it in a new browser.

Comment: Thank you, but this still just returns a 404, as-per my example above - plus all the rules are already above the final catch-all. I'm also testing via cURL so there's no response caching.

Comment: Actually, if I change to `RewriteRule ^news/?$ /insights [R=301,L,NC]` (no / before news), this seems to work. I'm still unsure why simply using `redirect` wasn't working though.

Comment: Indeed, `/` before `news` only matches in Apache config not in .htaccess. I have updated my rule to make it optional now so that it will work in both cases. Using `Redirect` is not recommended because other rule are using `mod_rewrite` based rules and it is not recommended to use different directives.

Comment: I didn't know that, I'll use this method from now on, thank you